# Mysql syntax error when inserting string using Python connector

Tags: python, mysql

very new to both MySQL and Python so any help would be appreciated.  This syntax error is driving me crazy because I feel like I'm following the tutorials exactly...

Here's my very simple DB:

```
>>> cursor.execute('DESCRIBE Sports_Master')
>>> cursor.fetchall()
[(u'ID', u'int(11)', u'NO', u'PRI', None, u'auto_increment'), (u'Name', u'varchar(255)', u'NO', u'', None, u'')]
```

What I'm attempting to do:

```
import mysql.connector
conn = mysql.connector.connect(**mysql_config)
cursor = conn.cursor()
test_name = 'Test'
insert_statement = ("INSERT INTO Sports_Master (Name) "
                    "VALUES (%s)"
                   )
cursor.execute(insert_statement, test_name)
```

And this is the resulting error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 507, in execute
self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 722, in cmd_query
result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 640, in _handle_result
raise errors.get_exception(packet)
ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1
```

Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIRC, The values that you pass in are supposed to be a non-string sequences (or mappings if you want to use the `%(name)` syntax).  tuples work nicely for what you're doing:

```
test_name = ('Test',)
```

Comment: You're a star thank you.  0 out of the 5 tutorials I looked at specified that values had to be non-string sequences... would think that would be important to note!  As for `(Name)` it just specifies that the value is being inserted into the Name column

Comment: Based on your edit, does this mean that `VALUES (%(name)s)` and `test_name = {'name': 'Test'}` would also work?

Comment: @SamWB -- I doubt it (But you're welcome to try and let me know ;-).  the DB has pretty stringent rules about where you can substitute what.  I don't think you can do table names.  I mean that:  `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES (%(value)s)', {'value': 'Test'})` should also work.

Comment: Apologies, my use of 'name' as the dict key was coincidental and I omitted the rest of the INSERT line out of laziness.  Thanks again for the help